# FineUploader onError Callback

Tags: modal-dialog, fine-uploader

my endpoinit in funeuploader sends back a aspecial error, which should open an dialog. Therefore I try to fetch this error in the callback

```
/ define fineUploader
$('div#' + thisUpload).fineUploader({
debug: data.debug_enable,
request: {
endpoint: '{url controller=Basketupload action=doUpload forceSecure}'
}
callbacks: {
onError: function(id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) {
//fetch the error and open dialog
$( ".qq-confirm-dialog-selector" ).dialog({...});
//
}
}
```

But the error is

```
[Fine Uploader 5.2.1] 
Caught exception in 'onError' callback - $(...).dialog is not a function
```

How can I stop it to go to "complete" and open a dialog, if the endpoints sends a a special error ?

Comment: the endpoint sends back

     return array( "success" => false, "dialog" => true, 
    "error"  =>  $response );

Comment: The error message tells you everything you need to know to solve this problem. There is no jquery dialog method on the element you are selecting.